# How to capture a text from the cucumber result after executing a feature file and pass it to another feature file as a test data?

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin, service-layer, cucumber-java

I have a feature file A.feature which generates a number in the response body. Now, I have to capture that text/number and then pass it as test data to another feature file.Do we need to write step definition or is there any other way?Please suggest.

Comment: I'm with @szabo in that your scenarios should be independent.

Comment: Dependencies between scenarios is a really bad idea. If you sant to seed a scenario, then do it explicit. Do not do it implicit by chaining two scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, you should not do that. In fact you should try to make your test cases totally independent from each other. It's a bad sign if a single code change breaks many of your tests (in your case, whenever the first feature breaks, the second one would as well.) It's also a bad sign that, as a starting point, your second feature needs a special response that is not easy to construct.